# How to give an API read permission on GitLab to only a single repository?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

It is possible on GitHub to authorize 3rd party app/service to only access a single repository. I did not find such possibility for GitLab, it seems that you can only give access to everything. Is it correct or there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Project Access tokens. You can limit them for different scopes and assign them even project based permissions, like `Maintainer`,`Developer`,`Reporter` etc.

You can find them within the project at `Settings > Access Tokens`.

[image]

In the meanwhile there is also a possibility to do this for Groups - you will find it at the same place within a group.

With those Settings you can give dedicated access to a single repository, even write access. If you only desire read access without api eg for deployments take a look at `Deploy Tokens` within `Settings > Repository`

Comment: Thanks. They are apparently not available on the free plan.`On GitLab SaaS if you have the Premium license tier or higher. Project access tokens are not available with a trial license.`

Answer (score 0):

you can authorize app/service access only on single Project using the Auth Token. Is not possible for a single Repository in the Project.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#create-a-project-access-token